# has_one :through and has_many :through

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
rails -v = 4.0
ruby -v = 2.1.1
```

I am having some serious problem with has_one :through. All of the google 1st 2 pages link are blue in color ( I have gone through all of them).

My problem is when I try to do

```
post = Post.last
post.build_user
```

It say **undefined method `build_user'**. My classes with associations are as follow.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
    has_one :user_post
    has_one :user, class_name: "User", through: :user_post

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class UserPost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_posts
    has_many :posts, through: :user_posts 
end
```

It would be really great if somebody please help to out to resolve this issue.

Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to setup a `Many-to-Many Relationship` between `Post` and `User` but your current setup is incorrect.

You need to use `has_many` instead of `has_one` in `Post` model.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :users, through: :user_posts
end
```

After this you can build the users as:

```
post = Post.last
post.users.build
```

**UPDATE**

You are getting error as `undefined method`build_user'.`because you can only use`post.build_user`if association between`Post`and`User`is`has_one` and defined as below:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post    # foreign key - post_id
end
```

**UPDATE 2**

Also, logically `A user has_many posts AND A post has one User` so your setup should ideally be

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user   # foreign key - user_id
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts    
end
```

After this you can build the posts for a user as:

```
user = User.last
user.posts.build
```

To build a user for a post:

```
post = Post.last
post.build_user
```

Comment: how can a post have more then one user?

Comment: Read my UPDATE section in the answer

Comment: Tricky one to sort out

Comment: Read my UPDATE2 also.

Comment: :), ideally true, but he wants to associate a premade post with a user. doesn't he?

Comment: @KirtiThorat, one user can have many posts, but on the other side a post can only have one user. This is what i want.

Comment: @user3269780 the relation she stated is doing just that

Comment: @user3269780 Thats what UPDATE 2 will do.

Comment: @KirtiThorat thanks I getting it little bit. But how i can go other way round, I want to build the user from post. i.e post = Post.last and then post.build_user.

Comment: Read the updated answer on how to build a user for a given post.

Comment: @user3269780 I thought issue was solved... didn't you want one user to have many posts and a single post can belong to only one user?

Comment: @user3269780 Did you read the UPDATE 2 completely, I added something at the end. Read it again and try to implement everything as suggested in UPDATE 2.